# How to write regex to replace spaces between span tags with &nbsp;

Tags: regex, c#-4.0

I want the space between the span tags to be replaced by `&nbsp;`

```
<span style="font-size:11;color:black"> </span>
```

I wrote this regex:

```
Regex.Replace(xml, @"<span[^>]*?>\s*</span>", (match) => match.Value.Replace(" ", "&nbsp;"), RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

But it give me this output:

```
<span&nbsp;style="font-size:11;color:black">&nbsp;</span>
```

It also places the `&nbsp;` after the span.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use

```
@"(?<=<span[^>]*?>)\s*(?=</span>)"
```

as your regex.

Be aware, that parsing HTML with regular expressions is frowned upon and will break horribly when encountering (among others) HTML Comments and JavaScript.

Comment: tx it worked but facing other problem when i load the replaced string with an XElement.Load(outputstrg).Element("body"); it throws an error for that &nbsp; Is there a way where I can make my replace string so that xml notices it has a space?

Comment: @Jack: Sure. Don't do the Regex.Replace and parse (or load) the file with LoadOptions.PreserveWhitespace.

Comment: @Jens: I think "frowned upon" is the wrong phrase. It's like saying comparisons between floating point numbers is frowned upon. It's not frowned upon, it's simply an incorrect solution to a problem. It may work in very specific instances, but in the real world there are probably more ways that it will fail than there are ways it will succeed.

Answer (score 0):

Use Regex.Replace

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"<span([^>]*)>\s*</span>");
String output = regex.Replace(input, "<span$1>&nbsp;</span>");
```